# Remove index.php? from URL with question mark | Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

Hi Dear Stackflow Community i am newbie in Codeignite coding so i hope you guys give me the time to fix this error thanks is advance :)
So basically i followed a tutorial here and i disabled index.php from URL that problem was fixed but i still have the remaining question mark ? i tried every tutorial here in stackflow eventually i manage to remove the index.php but the question mark remains so how to remove index.php? and finally have example.com/index.php?/signin to example.com/signin without index.php and ? mark
here is my htaccess folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)i=[^&]+(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
AddType text/vtt .vtt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

or the simple version of that:

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1
```

Comment: I tried both of them in htaccess it is the same problem now with your code index.php is back again and it shows like this example.com/index.php?/

Comment: You need to update the config.php inside config folder by removing index.php.
`$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this problem can be highly dependent on your Apache configuration and your web host configuration.

This code tries a slightly different approach, and is more aggressive about figuring out the extra ? and /. It will also bail out of infinite redirect, which can happen depending on your server config.

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: i tried it in my htaccess the index.php is gone but the questions mark ? remains please help me